# How to create layer group in geoserver with gsconfig?

Tags: python, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

How can I create layer groups using python gsconfig ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. Connect to Catalog**

```
 cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest","admin", "geoserver")
```

**2. Get some layers and styles**

```
lyrs = [list of layers]

stls = [list of styles]
```

**3. Create the group layer**

```
lg = cat.create_layergroup(groupname)
```

**4. Add the layers and styles to the group layer**

```
lg.layers = lyrs

lg.styles = stls
```

**5. Save the group layer**

```
cat.save(lg)
```

To specify a workspace I think you need to create a resource and then use that to create the group layer in step 3.

```
myResource = cat.get_resources(workspace='workspaceName') lg = 

cat.create_layergroup(myResource,groupname
```

Comment: How to create layer group in a particular workspace (choosing a workspace)..

Comment: How to edit/modify a already existed layer gruop?