# Uploading multiple layers to a layer group at once in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, layers

Is it possible to upload layers to a layer group at once to geoserver? I have about 1000 data and I want to upload them to one layer group. However, as I understand, I have to select them one by one for uploading. Is there any button such as select all?

Answer (score 1):

The GeoServer Importer Extension is what you are looking for ! :)

[GeoServer Importer Extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/index.html)

***There are two primary advantages to using the Importer over the standard GeoServer data-loading workflow:***

*1. Supports batch operations (loading and publishing multiple spatial files or database tables in one operation)*

*2. Creates unique styles for each layer, rather than linking to the same (existing) styles.*

**EDIT:**
A solution using python has been provided [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123390/162856)

Comment: Importer extension is used to import multiple files to geoserver. This is not my case. I have already 1000 layers in geoserver that are uploaded before. Now, I want to create a layer group from them and I am asking that is there a way to create a layer group by selecting all the layers at once?

Comment: Sorry I read your question too quickly !
I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of geoserver-rest  (https://geoserver-rest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and geoservers own REST interface to achieve this.

Since i had no luck using `create_layergroup()` from geoserver-rest, i made this rather hacky solution:

```
import requests

from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver
geo = Geoserver('http://ip:8080/geoserver_USA', username='xxxx', password='xxxx')


noaa_workspaces = ["NOAA_enc_overview","NOAA_enc_harbour","NOAA_enc_approach","NOAA_coastal","NOAA_general"]



for service in noaa_workspaces:
    #file = open(service + "_layers", "w+")
    print(service)
    layers = geo.get_layers(workspace=service)
    
    
    layer_list = []
    for x in range(len(layers["layers"]["layer"])):
        layer_list.append(layers["layers"]["layer"][x]["name"])
        print(layers["layers"]["layer"][x]["name"])
    
    
    layer_list.sort()
    xml=""
    for layer in layer_list:
        #print("<layer>%s:%s</layer>" % (service,layer))
        xml += "<layer>%s:%s</layer>" % (service,layer)
        #print(xml)
        #open(service, "a")
        #file.write("<layer>%s:%s</layer>" % (service,layer))   
        
    xml_final =  "<layerGroup><name>%s</name><layers>%s</layers></layerGroup>" % (service,xml)
    #print(xml)
    #print(xml_final)   

    headers =  {'Content-type' : 'text/xml'}
   # requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=xml, headers=headers).text

    print("send request for : ", service)
    print(requests.post('http://user:pass@ip:8080/geoserver_USA/rest/layergroups',data=xml_final, headers=headers).text)
```